# How to Display string text in html body?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm just starting with **ASP.NET, C# and HTML**.

I want to display a text message in the browser if an email was sent successfully.

How do I show in the HTML body the value of a variable that was previously defined in the script part of the `.aspx` file?

```
<script runat="server">    
    void SendAnEmail()
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
            string theResult = "Success! :)";
        }
        catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException)
        {
            string theResult = "Failure! :(";
        }            
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Send Mail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        ??????
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to invest your time learning such an old technology? Why not going for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @FrancescoLorenzetti84 Does it really mean 'why you eat *sandwich*, now we've *pizza*'

Comment: More like 'why are you flirting with grandma, your hot classmate is down for it'

Comment: @FrancescoLorenzetti84  try learning flirting , you can't go trail with hot classmate straight away practice with grandma :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the `asp:Literal` server control which it's syntax is:
`<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LiteralText"/>`

And assign text to it in code behind:
`LiteralText.Text = theResult;`

Comment: @RafaelSanchez You may also want to look at these articles since you are new to webform: http://blog.zay-dev.com/category/net/web-form/

Answer (score 0):

First, define an unique id for the HTML element that serves as placeholder for your message

```
<body>
    <div id="placeholderId"></div>
</body>
```

Then in your javascript, access the placeholder and insert HTML into it. I am using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for this.

```
<script type="javascript">
    function SendAnEmail() {
      // ...
      var theResult = 'some string';
      var placeholder = $('#placeholderId'); // jQuery selector by id
      placeholder.html(theResult); // set HTML content of placeholder element
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT**: this will not work for the scenario of OP, because this assumes that `theResult` is available as Javascript variable. But OP uses `<script runat="server">` to execute C# code.

Comment: Just curious, is that executable when `<script runat="server">` and the `theResult` is set at server side?

Comment: Actually, this would be `<script type="javascript">` which runs on the client. I didn't note that OP uses `<script runat="server">` to run a C# method 'SendAnEmail', so I guess this would not work.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what does JavaScript got to do with anything here? Is the script always written in JavaScript when using .NET?

Comment: @Rafael I read the question wrong. You are using C# on the server to send the email. My answer only works if you send the email from the client, e.g. using AJAX. Sorry for creating confusion.